# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35624972 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 28MB until OOM

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, options);
options.inSampleSize = 2;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

As you can see from the code,I have tried to optimize the bitmap,and it works for me in all situations except in Android Studio 2.0 virtual device(nexus 6p API23),Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried to optimize the bitmap" -- no, you have not. You find out the size of the resource... and then totally ignore that result, hard-coding `inSampleSize` to 2. Your first `decodeResource()` call is pointless. Your resource is much too large or is in the wrong directory, as you are attempting to load what amounts to a 2984px by 2984px image.

Comment: Try using the methods outlined in [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare and @petey,[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This alerts you that in some devices you could have memory problems doing this. Try resizing the image to reduce his size. You also can set a larger memory heap witting  android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest but i wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: why you wouldn't recommend largeHeap="true"? its there to be used.